# How to uninstall software?

Tags: 22.04, snap

I already have Snap store/[Ubuntu Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEdLX.png). But in past, I installed this [Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRcaR.png). Now both Snap and this software are showing me updates. I wanted to uninstall this [Software.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn5pP.png)
I wanted to know what this software is and how it differs from regular Snap. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `snap list` to list installed snaps to determine the snap to be deleted.

Then you can use `sudo snap remove <snap-name>` to delete.

Answer (score 0):

The app you are referring to is called Gnome Software.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software

It is completely normal to have it installed if you are using the Gnome desktop, and it is, traditionally, the usual way of installing things on Ubuntu using the Gnome desktop.  It can install software from a range of sources, but depending which version you have, it has removed support for the Snap Store.

The other one, called "Ubuntu Software" is another name for the Snap Store.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(software)

It can install software from Ubuntu sources only (packages from Apt and snap packages from the Snap Store only).

You can use whichever you like, and there is no need to uninstall the one you don't want to use.